# Joining Multiple MySQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

another MySQL question. I can do almost anything I want to in PHP, but the second MySQL comes into place that's considered intermediate I go brain dead. You'll probably roll your eyes on this one as well, but it's got me stuck. I really want to learn how to do this correctly so I'll be doing tutorials while I wait for some ideas from people.

I have a reservation session that's stored in a variable called $sessionID, and I'm creating a menu table that has a list of dishes for this particular reservation. I have it pulling the table of dishes perfectly, but now I need to get a number of orders that were made for this reservation for each dish.

```
orders2
id, session

order_items2
id, ord, dish
```

Those are pretty much the relevant pieces for this question. I need to search a total number of order items where orders2.session = $sessionID and orders2.id = order_items2.ord and order_items2.dish = $dishID. I can do the fun stuff afterwards, but I'm struggling with the query myself.

```
$SQL2ORDERSEARCH = "
    SELECT * FROM order_items2
    INNER JOIN orders2
    on (orders2.id = order_items2.ord)
    WHERE orders2.session = '$sessionID'
    AND order_items2.dish = '$searchitems_object->dish'
";
```

This was my latest attempt, so you at least had something to laugh at. Hope I've given you enough info and I greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Think you just need to skip the () in the ON part..

```
SELECT * FROM order_items2
INNER JOIN orders2
ON orders2.id = order_items2.ord
WHERE orders2.session = '$sessionID'
AND order_items2.dish = '$searchitems_object->dish'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately this rendered me zero results.

Comment: If your still struggling maybe you should verify your variables, and test the query directly in mysql. And perhaps post some of your table data..